# Using PictureBox as a TrackBar in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, trackbar

I'm making a trakbar with a picture in the pictureBox. By clicking that trackbar, there must be a black vertical line. But there is a problem shown below.

http://j1307.hizliresim.com/1c/8/q0rh1.png

Comment: Try starting the program with admin rights and see if the error occurs again. The problem is, that C:\ is only writeable with admin rights.

Comment: Problem occurs again... i change the C:\ with D:\ but the problem occurs...

Comment: Try changing system.drawing.image.fromfile into system.drawing.bitmap.fromfile if possible. Otherwise add imageformat.bmp as the second argument to the erroring save method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that shoe-horning a DateTime into a string won't give you a supported filename for the image to save to.

As example:

```
String fileName = "C:\\" + DateTime.Now + ".bmp";
File.Create(fileName);
```

will throw an error because `fileName` gives you a path of `C:\08/07/2013 12:41:39.bmp` - which is not a valid file path.

To fix this you would format the DateTime potion of your string to something more palatable, like

```
String formattedDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":","-");
String fileName = String.Format(@"C:\{0}.bmp", formattedDateTime);
File.Create(fileName);
```

This would give you a filename like `C:\2013-07-08T12-48-57.bmp` which will not only save but is sort-able as well.

So finally, to apply this to your code, you would use

```
String formattedDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":","-") ;
String fileName = String.Format(@"C:\{0}.bmp", formattedDateTime);
img.Save(fileName);
```